# Ember 2.0 with Ember-CLI, how to access 'document.location.host'?

Tags: browser, ember.js, session-variables, ember-cli, javascript-objects

Putting following line e.g. in app/controllers/application.js

`console.log(document.location.host);`

will not work, as the browser-context is not present.
What is the alternative? It should also work with other javascript objects.

solved: it was a structure error (novice)

`import Ember from 'ember';`

`export default Ember.Controller.extend({
   myInfo:'test',
   i: console.log(document.location.host)
});`
is working. Important is to put 'i:' or 'initialize:' on a freshly generated controller (after `ember g controller app`) as {} expects of course a js-hash-object and not a sequence of statements.

Comment: Can you provide full code for this controller?

Comment: do you mean window.location.host?

Comment: What makes you think the browser context is not present?

Comment: console.log(document.location.host) works everywhere in controller code

Comment: You should post this as an answer and mark it as accepted @Jean Fontaine so other's know you solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I just had to be aware that `.extend(...)` is not expecting code-statements per se, but a Mixin-class. So practically it needs a property-name (e.g. `i` or `mySpecialInit` syntactically followed by colon `:` and a function or here directly a statement `console.log(document.location.host)` ).